# Key Advantages of ASP.net CORE over Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

What are the **Key Advantages** of `ASP.net` `CORE` over `ASP.net`, and When we can start using this new Framework?

I have just read some article about `ASP.net` `CORE` but could not found sufficient Answer.

Can anybody help me into this for understanding about `ASP.net` `CORE`.

Thanks

Comment: This is not opinion based actually.  There are technical differences and this post in essence is asking for a list of areas in which .Net Core has an advantage.  Advantages in technology are known and defined, and thus not opinions.  Such items include but are not limited too, Total Size, Extensibility, Memory Size, Compatibility, Functionality provided, Integration into existing IDE's, etc..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From my point of view the key advantages are:

1. `ASP.NET Core` is [cross platform](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html#what-is-asp-net-core), so you can run it on Windows, Linux and Mac.
2. It can handle [a lot more requests](http://web.ageofascent.com/asp-net-core-exeeds-1-15-million-requests-12-6-gbps/).
3. You don't need to install the .NET Framework to run it. Instead, you ship all the required dlls with your application.
4. You can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) to develop your application, which is free and lightweight in comparison to Visual Studio. And you can use it on different platforms as well.

Of course there are more differences, the [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html#what-is-asp-net-core) is a good place to get an overview.